# how to sort elements in a list in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a list elements as follows

```
simple_list <- list(c(3,1,2))
```

Can anyone please let me know how to get the sort the above list in ascending as well as descending order?

**Note:-** Please tell me without using the list's `unlist()`

Answer (score 3):

```
result.ordered <- result[order(names(result))]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for your list:

```
lapply(simple_list,sort,decreasing=FALSE)
lapply(simple_list,sort,decreasing=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've created a list of vectors, but in this case - a list of one vector.

In case you want to sort that vector,  use this:

```
simple_list <- c(3, 1, 2)
simple_list <- sort(simple_list, decreasing = FALSE)
print(simple_list)
```

To sort in ascending order, specify *decreasing* to FALSE, to sort in descending order – set it to TRUE.