# How to recreate a list in R so that its fields are printed alphabetically?

Tags: r

I have a long list which is created dynamically and looks something like this (but with many more fields)

```
  l <- list()
  l$col.in <- 0
  l$dt.in <- data.frame()
  l$col.out <- 1
  l$dt.out <- data.frame()
```

when I print it, it shows up in order its field were populated:

```
>   l
$col.in
[1] 0

$dt.in
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$col.out
[1] 1

$dt.out
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

I need it to be printed in such a way that all  its fields showup in alphabetical order, like below:

```
>   l.sorted
$col.in
[1] 0

$col.out
[1] 1

$dt.in
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$dt.out
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

How can I do that?
Please create a new list l.sorted which would be printed as desired. Thank you

Comment: `l.sorted <- l[order(names(l))]` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031413/10276092

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
l.sorted <- l[order(names(l))]
l.sorted
# $col.in
# [1] 0
# $col.out
# [1] 1
# $dt.in
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
# $dt.out
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

The first version of this used `sort`, but that fails when one or more names are empty. For example,

```r
l <- list(d=1, 2, a=3)
l
# $d
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# $a
# [1] 3
l[sort(names(l))]
# $<NA>
# NULL
# $a
# [1] 3
# $d
# [1] 1
l[order(names(l))]
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# $a
# [1] 3
# $d
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple fix can be to return the sorted indices.

```r
l[sort(names(l))]
```

EDIT:
r2evans was faster with the right answer.